# Android SIGSEV 11 fast scroll of ViewPager

Tags: android, segmentation-fault

I'm getting

> A/libc(26509): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x0000000c (code=1), thread 26509 (ct.universaldev)

sometimes when scrolling `ViewPager` with `Fragment`'s very fast. The app is compatible only with 4.0+ devices, also I don't out of memory (tracked with MAT and Little Eye) and using `largeHeap` attribute. Also it doesn't look like I'm having memory leaks (at least significant).

I don't receive any Java errors/exceptions before this one. How can I even understand what is the reason if this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was intercepting touch events in my `Fragment` subclasses using `OnTouchListener` attached to their top views. In this listener I was doing some "strange" stuff with event finally storing a local copy of `MotionEvent` object which was released in `OnTouchListener's` finalize method. After "decoding" native stacktrace I found out that crashed appeared sometimes on `MotionEvent.release()` method call. I refactored my code making that `OnTouchListener` unnecessary and that solved the problem.